# Is changing or editing a jquery variable possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, client-side

I am getting a variable value on click function i want to remove last 5 letters and put my own three letters to that variable is that possible?
For example **Var hhh** has value like **"goodday"** now i want to remove **day** and insert **night** in hhh.so now it should have "goodnight"Is this possible, if possible then how?

Comment: There's not really any such thing as a "jQuery variable". You could argue that a "jQuery variable" is a *JavaScript* variable that references a jQuery object, but that's not what you're talking about here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you literally only ever want to change the string "goodday" to the string "goodnight" then you can use `replace`. However, that seems a little absurd, since if that were the case you could simply do `hhh = "goodnight"` and cut that out entirely. I'd assume you want something more generic, so use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to get all but the last three characters in the string:

```
var hhh = "goodday";
hhh = hhh.substring(0, hhh.length - 3); // hhh == "good"
hhh = hhh + "night"; // hhh == "goodnight"
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can try this:

```
var hhh = "goodDay";
hhh = hhh.substring(0, hhh.length - 3) + "night";
alert(hhh);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hhh = "goodday";
hhh = hhh.replace('day','night'); //if only first occurence need to be replaced
```

Comment: ok.now i just wanted to remove **ood** and leave remain like **gday** is that too possible?

Comment: @roasted No, they want you to do more than post very specific (and arguably useless) code and actually explain how these things work. That's kind of the point of the site.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Sorry but im just tired of this kind of user that show absolutely no effort, no initiative and just come here to get snippet for their client. That's my point of view. I'm maybe wrong, maybe.

Comment: @roasted This is not for any client I'm learning for my purpose anyway thanks for your consideration. Don't think like this for all people like me(newbie) who are in stack overflow.

Comment: The best way to learn is to test by your own side. And if you are stuck somewhere, then you can ask for some help. Have you tried to search by yourself before asking this question on SO. I don't think so...

Comment: Thanks i'm trying and i'll try my level best

Comment: Ok, raj, i hope you the best :)

Answer (score 0):

may be use

```
split();
```

so you can remove letters ant than add through

```
for(;;);?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var h = 'goodday';
h = h.replace('day','night');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample http://jsfiddle.net/BMY3n/

```
$('#btN').click(function(){
var str = "Good Day"
alert(str.replace('Day','Night'));
});
```

You can use replace function available in javascript. I have given the sample for better clarity